# Applying label to svg path

Tags: html, svg

I am looking to apply a label underneath a SVG path representing a hamburger menu icon.  However, depsite trying various options, I am so far unable to force the text below, it only appears to the right, as per the screenshot below:

[image]

I have tried:

- Putting an SVG `<text>MENU</text>` underneath `<path>` (i.e. `<svg><path></path><text></text></svg>`).  However in this instance the "MENU" text does not appear at all.
- The current attempt shown in my sample code whereby I simply appended the text after the `</svg>` closing tag.

My sample code can be found at https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-currying-ww68b?file=/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1:**

Remove `inline-flex` class of `<button>`.

**Method 2:**

Modify the code to:

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<button type="button" class="items-center justify-center p-2 rounded-md text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500 hover:bg-gray-100 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-500 transition duration-150 ease-in-out" id="main-menu" aria-label="Main menu"
  aria-haspopup="true">
   <svg
      class="h-10 w-10"
      stroke="currentColor"
      fill="none"
      viewBox="0 0 40 40"
      >
      <path
         stroke-linecap="round"
         stroke-linejoin="round"
         stroke-width="2"
         d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h16"
         />
      <text x="0" y="35" font-size="12">MENU</text>
   </svg>
</button>
```